# Why access mode r+ does not allow truncation and appends the new data instead of overwrite?

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, truncate

I have checked around but I cannot find the answer to my question. 
It is about access mode r+ in the read() function in Python. I

The setup is the following:

1. I have a test.txt file containing, say, three rows with 11, 12, 13.
2. I have code.py file containing the following:

```
script, filename = argv

print("Opening the file...")
target=open(filename, 'r+')

print("currently in the file: ")
print(target.read())

print("Truncating the file")
target.truncate()

print("input three lines.")
line1 = input("line 1: ")
line2 = input("line 2: ")
line3 = input("line 3: ")

target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")

print("Now we close the file. Bye.")
target.close()
```

3. I run from the command line: python code.py test.txt

The read() function is executed, I see the 11,12,13 output to the command window.

I presume truncate() runs as well.

Then I input three new lines, say 66, 67, 68.

When I open the test.txt file I see in one column 11,12,13,66,67,68.

I expected truncate() to delete all the data inside the test.txt file and then r+ to write the 66,67,68 in there, instead of appending these lines.

Could someone explain to me why this happens?

I do not understand the logic, and the descriptions for access modes do not help (well, I understood that w/w+ truncates (=deletes all the data) on file open).

AND, if I replace target.truncate() with target.truncate(0) then the 11,12,13 are deleted and I see in one column 66, 67, 68 where 66 is indented ten spaces. What is happening here??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Because you specify no size `truncate` reduces to the current position. In `r` mode it's the end of the file. Try `truncate(0)`